# How do I copy a datetime from one database to another in Symfony 3.4 +?

Tags: symfony, datetime

In Table "A" I have a field "created" with a Symfony entity match the field as a datetime type.

In Table "B" I have the same created field of type DateTime and matching entity of datetime type.

In my code if I wish to simply copy that date over I am getting the dreaded format error that basically is saying a string was passed instead of a datetime. I'm doing something like this:

```
$tableB = new TableB();
$em->persist( $tableB );
$tableB->setCreated( $tableA->getCreated() );
$em->flush();
```

Anyone have any idea how to copy the date over correctly?

The exact error I am getting is:

```
Error: Call to a member function format() on string
in vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/DateTimeType.php (line 53)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was mistaken and was grabbing a different date that was stored as a string. My mistake. Thanks anyhow.